# GAE - why Post request has parameters exposed in URL?

Tags: google-app-engine

I have simple post request to cloud endpoint

```
    @ApiMethod(name = "insertEmployee", httpMethod = HttpMethod.POST)
public Employee insertEmployee(@Named("phoneNumber") Long phoneNumber,
                             @Named("emailId") String emailId) { ... }
```

which accepts request of form

POST http://localhost:8888/_ah/api/employeeendpoint/v1/employee/87900850/q%40m.com

Is there something wrong with API design or url is wrong?

i have used REST client from browser to query localhost as well as deployment.

Comment: There are no parameters in the URL that you posted.

Comment: @Andrei phoneNumber and emailId values are exposed in URL as 87900850 and q@m.com

Comment: These are parts of a URL path. Why are you concerned with them being exposed? From a security point of view there is no difference between putting data in the body or in the URL path.